# SQL Invalid Argument Error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am receiving an error when I try to save my query.

```
SELECT tbl_2_trip_details_2012.Arrival_ID, Count(tbl_2_trip_details_2012.Arrival_ID) AS        CountOfArrival_ID
FROM tbl_2_trip_details_2012
GROUP BY tbl_2_trip_details_2012.Arrival_ID
HAVING (((tbl_2_trip_details_2012.Arrival_ID)=84252114));
```

The query pulls fine, but when I try to save under any name it errors out and states "Invalid Argument".
Please help!!!

Comment: Instead of a Having clause why don't you use a Where above the Group by?

Comment: Try compacting & repairing the database and then try saving the query.

Comment: what is the datatype of `Arrival_ID`?  If it is a string you might need to place quotes around it.

Comment: What happens when you have no Where or having clause?

Comment: Tim, your compact and repair worked great.  I now can save the query.  I need to remember to Keep It Simple!  Thanks!!!

Comment: BF, the data type is Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
  SELECT tbl_2_trip_details_2012.Arrival_ID, Count(tbl_2_trip_details_2012.Arrival_ID) AS          CountOfArrival_ID
  FROM tbl_2_trip_details_2012
  where tbl_2_trip_details_2012.Arrival_ID=84252114
  GROUP BY tbl_2_trip_details_2012.Arrival_ID
```

Comment: Still gives the invalid argument.