# How to sum up with SQL values in previous rows in SELECT query in Access?

Tags: sql, select, sum, window-functions

I have a table named "new_meetings":

```
(ID_to, meetdate, amount)
-------------------------
(0, 01.07.2004, 3)
(0, 14.07.2004, 1)
(0, 11.02.2008, 5)
(1, 11.02.2008, 2)
(1, 12.02.2008, 1)
```

So I need and sql query, that will give me the result:

```
(0, 01.07.2004, 3)
(0, 14.07.2004, 4)
(0, 11.02.2008, 9)
(1, 11.02.2008, 2)
(1, 12.02.2008, 3)
```

I use Access.
I've tried the following:

```
SELECT meetdate, amount,
(SELECT SUM(*) FROM new_meetings WHERE n.ID_to = new_meetings.ID_to AND new_meetings.meetdate<=n.meetdate) as total
FROM new_meetings n
```

But get the strange error: "Invalid function argument"
So what should I perform?

Answer (score 3):

It's called running total. Here you'll find complete samples:
[How do I... Generate a running total in an Access query?](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-do-i-generate-a-running-total-in-an-access-query/)
[Using MS Access to create a Running Total or a Cumulative Sum – Part 1 of 2](https://theaccessbuddy.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/using-ms-access-to-create-a-running-total-or-a-cumulative-sum-part-1-of-2/)

```
SELECT meetdate, amount, 
    (SELECT SUM(amount)
     FROM new_meetings
     WHERE n.ID_to = new_meetings.ID_to
         AND new_meetings.meetdate<=n.meetdate) as total
FROM new_meetings n
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am still getting the error "Invalid function argument" on this code.

Comment: What `meetdate` field is data type?

Comment: I tried to reconstruct your issue, but no success. Query works as well. Try to repair and compact your database. In this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606383/sql-invalid-argument-error it helped.

Comment: Ok, I can't mark your answer as correct, because it doesn't work for me, but I've givven +1. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
Select m1.id_to, m1.meetdate, sum(m2.amount)
From new_meetings m1
LEFT Join new_meetings m2
On m1.id_to=m2.id_to
And m2.meetdate<= m1.meetdate
Group by m1.id_to, m1.meetdate
```